# Build fail with error ld: file not found: -fobjc-arc

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker, automatic-ref-counting

I have added some advertisements sdk in my app like admob, revmob. When I am compiling my code I am getting the following error in my log,

```
ld: file not found: -fobjc-arc
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[image]

I have converted non-arc files into arc by setting `-fno-objc-arc` in my compile source.

Comment: you must check your target's build settings and build phase. I think you have entered a value with wrong escapes and it is leading to passing wrong compiler flags. for example you might added some unwanted " or ' or other wildcard characters in build settings' values.

Comment: What have actually done flagged non-arc files with `-fobjc-arc` or `-fno-objc-arc`? Check if you have added `-fobjc-arc` for some files by mistake.